# Semi-comedic anime OVA involving a demonic invasion of a high school

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this on VHS in the original Japanese, subtitled to English, in the 1990s, on a tape my brother brought back from college. On that tape, or others he brought, was *[The Fuma Conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fuma_Conspiracy)* and some episodes of *[Kimagure Orange Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimagure_Orange_Road)*. The protagonist is a high school female who fights demons, and has to deal with an incursion at her high school, which is set in roughly contemporary times. I don't think that most people had access to any sort of magic or powers. She had long hair and wore a school uniform. I think she had a romantic interest who was in sports (basketball, I want to say) and there was another female with short hair (blond?) who was a cheerleader (I think she was wearing her cheerleading outfit), who tried to seduce said love interest by removing her top when they were alone. The demons themselves were on the ridiculous side of things, grotesquely colored and shaped, with themed attacks, although the only two I distinctly recall was one employing a large amount of thorned vines (and I want to say he had a stereotypical European accent, maybe French or Italian, with a lot of gratuitous English, or maybe speaking in another European language with subtitles) and another being a pair of female demons who employed an attack based on breasts (with a ridiculous shouted name) that my brother pointed out was supposed to be a riff on *Sailor Moon* and Sailor Uranus's [Star Gentle Uterus](https://sailormoon.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Gentle_Uterus) attack. I want to say there was something in that scene where that attack, or the deflection thereof, had someone thrown into a convenient soccer net.

I think that the heroine actually fails in preventing the demonic invasion, but I do remember it ended with the demons and humans co-existing peacefully, with scenes of them walking side by side.

I vaguely recall that the love interest (and maybe the female friend who tried to seduce him) had their own attempts at using themed attacks, shouting out the name while doing something mundane like throwing balls or ribbons at the demons.

It did not feel episodic. It might have been movie-length, but I think it was more of a "single episode [OVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_video_animation)", maybe 30-45 minutes at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Bakuen Campus Guardress*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=926) or, as I saw it, *Combustible Campus Guardress*, released as 4 half-hour episodes in 1994.

(summary from [TV Tropes.org](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/BakuenCampusGuardress))

> Every 3,000 years, a portal to the Demon World opens up, and demons are unleashed upon us. 3,000 years ago, a human-born Key named Kairei closed it. The Gateway District of Tokyo was built around it, and the residents were taught magic in order to be able to defend themselves.
>
> Now, the portal is about to open again.
>
> Meanwhile, Hazumi Jinno is your average schoolgirl save for the fact that she carries a large wooden sword and vies with her mother for the affection of her not-blood-related brother Takumi. And manages to beat the crap out of anyone who takes a peek at her panties. But Takumi turns out to be the reincarnation of Kairei, and soon, Hazumi is facing head remnant Kijima Touta. As well as dudes with guns for necks, a stereotyped Parisian and a seductress whose hair at one point sprouts flowers.

Found it via scanning the contents of the Wikipedia OVAs by Year index, and found it on the [1994 anime OAVs page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1994_anime_OVAs). The name jumped out at me, and a quick search confirmed it.

Takumi is the basketball playing love interest (who is also her not-blood-related brother) and Hime is the cheerleader also after him. And I did find the breast attack at around 1:37:00 in, "Combination attack: Sexy Dyna-Bust", which includes several flashes of pinup poses. And indeed, with the counterattack, one of the villains winds up in a soccer net (the other buried waist deep headfirst into the ground), mumbling "Goal" in English.

### Trailer

(note, has upper body nudity due to clothing damage)